# Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-anydpi-v21/somexmlFile.xml only in Lenovo devices

Tags: android, xml, vector

I am using a svg icon as vector asset in my android app, it was converted successfully and working fine in all device except lenovo devices.

I am many svg icons as vector asset all are working fine only one causes this and only in lenovo devices.

Error Log is:

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-anydpi-v21/ic_instagram.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f070081
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2884)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2768)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:932)
       at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:465)
       at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:358)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:198)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
       at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:85)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:93)
       at com.followersLikerBooster.adapter.SocialMediaAdapter$ViewHolder.setData(SocialMediaAdapter.kt:33)
       at com.followersLikerBooster.adapter.SocialMediaAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SocialMediaAdapter.kt:26)
       at com.followersLikerBooster.adapter.SocialMediaAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SocialMediaAdapter.kt:14)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3225)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:788)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:648)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
       at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.onMeasure(CardView.java:258)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:788)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:648)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:825)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:511)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:739)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:811)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:141)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:788)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:648)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:788)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:648)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2747)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2485)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1444)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1698)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1325)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6741)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:912)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:714)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:649)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:898)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

file that causes this issue is:

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="551.034"
    android:viewportWidth="551.034" android:width="24dp"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:pathData="M386.9,0H164.2C73.6,0 0,73.6 0,164.2v222.7c0,90.5 73.6,164.2 164.2,164.2h222.7c90.5,0 164.2,-73.6 164.2,-164.2V164.2C551,73.6 477.4,0 386.9,0zM495.6,386.9c0,60 -48.7,108.7 -108.7,108.7H164.2c-60,0 -108.7,-48.7 -108.7,-108.7V164.2c0,-60 48.7,-108.7 108.7,-108.7h222.7c60,0 108.7,48.7 108.7,108.7L495.6,386.9L495.6,386.9z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="151819.2336362915"
                android:endY="-302360.40860107425"
                android:startX="151819.2336362915"
                android:startY="-1964.225364379883" android:type="linear">
                <item android:color="#FFE09B3D" android:offset="0.0"/>
                <item android:color="#FFC74C4D" android:offset="0.3"/>
                <item android:color="#FFC21975" android:offset="0.6"/>
                <item android:color="#FF7024C4" android:offset="1.0"/>
            </gradient>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:pathData="M275.5,133C196.9,133 133,196.9 133,275.5s63.9,142.5 142.5,142.5S418,354.1 418,275.5S354.1,133 275.5,133zM275.5,362.6c-48.1,0 -87.1,-39 -87.1,-87.1s39,-87.1 87.1,-87.1c48.1,0 87.1,39 87.1,87.1C362.6,323.6 323.6,362.6 275.5,362.6z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="151819.2336362915"
                android:endY="-302360.40860107425"
                android:startX="151819.2336362915"
                android:startY="-1964.225364379883" android:type="linear">
                <item android:color="#FFE09B3D" android:offset="0.0"/>
                <item android:color="#FFC74C4D" android:offset="0.3"/>
                <item android:color="#FFC21975" android:offset="0.6"/>
                <item android:color="#FF7024C4" android:offset="1.0"/>
            </gradient>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:pathData="M418.3,134.1m-34.2,0a34.2,34.2 0,1 1,68.3 0a34.2,34.2 0,1 1,-68.3 0">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="230503.0311102295"
                android:endY="-302360.40860107425"
                android:startX="230503.0311102295"
                android:startY="-1964.225364379883" android:type="linear">
                <item android:color="#FFE09B3D" android:offset="0.0"/>
                <item android:color="#FFC74C4D" android:offset="0.3"/>
                <item android:color="#FFC21975" android:offset="0.6"/>
                <item android:color="#FF7024C4" android:offset="1.0"/>
            </gradient>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
</vector>
```

This code is different than other icons which are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue by replacing current instagram icon(which causes this issue) with some other icon and now it's working fine in lenovo devices, that is not the actual solution of the problem but the **problem was in that svg icon and i replaced it**.
I hope it would help someone.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that you're using a gradient, and these are only supported in API 24+.